# Check whether a skin file actually exists

Tags: skin, blocks

I want to check if a file exists in any skin and thus the result of `$block->getSkinUrl('foo.png')` points to a valid URL.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: suppose there exists multiple occurrences of same name in different folders. Then how do you want to manage this situation?

Comment: It should just be the normal fallback.

Comment: Here is a wild idea. Somehow get all the themes you have in your fallback mechanism (I don't know how, that's why is a wild idea) then do a `glob('skin/fronend/*/*/foo.png')` and see if any of the results match one of the themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

```
/**
 * Get skin URL of image in language specific version - fall back to English (en)
 * @param $ressource string - %s for language
 */
public function getSkinUrlFallback($resource)
{
    $file = sprintf($resource, $this->getLang());
    $skinBase = Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure());
    $skinUrl = $this->getSkinUrl($file);
    $path = str_replace($skinBase, '', $skinUrl);
    if (file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('skin') . DS . $path)) {
        return $skinUrl;
    } else {
        $file = sprintf($resource, 'en');
        return $this->getSkinUrl($file);
    }
}
```